# Only last object inside for loop is being saved in Django Python

Tags: python, django

When I loop through for loop, only last comment object is getting saved. 
I'm instantiating the object every time in the loop. Do I need to pass anything else after `save()` method in for loop?

Here is my code in **views.py** file :

```
def create_form(request):

    post = Post()
    post.name = 'Post Tite'
    post.save()

    listofmessages = [{'message':'comment1'},{'message':'comment2'},{'message':'comment3'}]

    for obj in listofmessages:

        comments = Comments()
        comments.post = post
        comments.message = obj['message']
        comments.save()

    return render(request, 'post/news_post.html', {})
```

Code in **models.py** file:

```
    class Post(models.Model):
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

        objects = UserManager()


    class Comments(models.Model):
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        message = models.CharField(max_length=5000, default='')

        objects = UserManager()
```

Comment: I this the real code? `obj` is a `dict` you will get `AttributeError` at `obj.message`. Also `list` is a built-in keyword, I hope you know what you are doing.

Comment: are you sure the last one is getting saved?? from the code it seems it will throw you an error according to your model design

Comment: @AamirAdnan, please check the edits. The last object is being saved successfully.

Comment: @Anirudh No I still don't think it is saving any object, you are not passing in the required `post` object while creating a comment. There should be an `IntegrityError`.

Comment: @AamirAdnan sorry, there was a typo

Comment: What does the `UserManager` do?

Comment: @schwobaseggl I'm using custom user